# "Over" as "when"/"while"

Tags: word-meaning

I've seen the following phrase as subtitles:

> Everyone is losing it over hearing that he also participates.

On [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/over), one definition seems to be about this case, even though there's no straight match:

> 19. in reference to, concerning, or about: *to quarrel over a matter.*

Am I right about this definition?
Can *over* be replaced by *when* or *while* in my example?

Comment: In this case, the definition of over is "on the subject of".  People are "losing it", and the reason for this is his participation.  Another use might be someone who lost their job over a poor review.  The poor review is the cause of the loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not replace over with when or while.

Don't confuse the reason for something with the time that something occurred.

> Everyone is losing it *due to* hearing that he also participates
>
> Everyone is losing it *because they are* hearing that he also participates
>
> Everyone is losing it *in reference to* hearing that he also participates

There is no explicit mention of time in the above sentences.  As opposed to:

> Everyone heard that he also participates, and were fine with it, but then I told them X, and now everyone is losing it.

Answer (score 0):

over

to fight over something

to lose it over something

To disagree over something

To moan over something (complain)

over is used to mean: **as regards something**; it is standard usage. It can either be viewed as a phrasal verb or in a prepositional phrase. It is used very frequently in a negative context.